# Adding a RSS Feed Image using XSL

Tags: xslt, rss

I have an RSS Feed which I am publishing to Facebook

The problem is the image does not appear but the description and titles are working fine. We use a XSL document to create the feed and I believe the problem lies here:

RSS feed: www.khl.com/access-international

XSL used to generate image:

```
  <item>
    <title><xsl:value-of select="name"/></title>
    <link>http://www.khl.com<xsl:value-of select="$magazine_path" />/detail/<xsl:value-of select="link" /></link>
    <description><xsl:value-of select="description"/><![CDATA[
        <img src="http://www.khl.com{item-links/item-link[@id=2]/items/item[1]/derived-files/preview}"/><img alt="" 
             border="0" 
             src="http://www.khl.com{item-links/item-link[@id=2]/items/item[1]/derived-files/preview}" 
             />
    ]]></description>
    <pubDate><xsl:apply-templates select="creation-date" mode="date-format"/><xsl:value-of select="substring(creation-date,11,16)"/><xsl:text>:</xsl:text>00 GMT</pubDate>
    <guid>http://www.khl.com<xsl:value-of select="$magazine_path" />/detail/<xsl:value-of select="link" /></guid>
      </item>
```

Any help would be appreciated,

Regards,
Sam

---

I have updated our feed and there is still no luck.

The code used in the XSL document now reads

```
 <item>
  <title><xsl:value-of select="name"/></title>
  <link>http://www.khl.com<xsl:value-of select="$magazine_path" />/detail/<xsl:value-of select="link" /></link>
  <description>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="description"/>
    <img src="http://www.khl.com{item-links/item-link[@id=2]/items/item[1]/derived-files/thumbnail}"/>
    <img alt="" border="0" src="http://www.khl.com{item-links/item-link[@id=2]/items/item[1]/derived-files/thumbnail}" />
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;</xsl:text>
  </description>
  <pubDate><xsl:apply-templates select="creation-date" mode="date-format"/><xsl:value-of select="substring(creation-date,11,16)"/><xsl:text>:</xsl:text>00 GMT</pubDate>
  <guid>http://www.khl.com<xsl:value-of select="$magazine_path" />/detail/<xsl:value-of select="link" /></guid>
</item>
</xsl:template>
```

I have re-checked the XML and it is also correct and pointing to the image. The Feed can be found here: www.khl.com/access-international. There are still no image tags

Hopefully I have done something wrong

Comment: Can you update your question to show a snippet of the XML you are trying to transform?

Answer (score 1):

Although the standard is (I believe) to use CDATA sections when you wish the description to contain HTML, the problem you have is your CDATA section is a section in your XSLT, and so will be processed when the XSLT document is initially parsed. In other words, anything within the CDATA section is just treated as text, so the use of Attribute Value Templates here is irrelevant.

You requirement is for the CDATA section to be part of the XML you are outputting. Now, there is a "cdata-section-elements" attribute available on **xsl:output**, but this only affects the serialization of text nodes, but not of elements and attributes. So, what you could do is effectively 'serialise' the HTML yourself, like so

```
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>
<img src="http://www.khl.com{item-links/item-link[@id=2]/items/item[1]/derived-files/preview}"/>
```

i.e, you are writing out the CDATA section manually here, so CDATA is written to the output, but is not treated as CDATA in the initial loading of the XSLT.

Try the following code:

```
<item>
  <title><xsl:value-of select="name"/></title>
  <link>http://www.khl.com<xsl:value-of select="$magazine_path" />/detail/<xsl:value-of select="link" /></link>
  <description>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="description"/>
    <img src="http://www.khl.com{item-links/item-link[@id=2]/items/item[1]/derived-files/preview}"/>
    <img alt="" border="0" src="http://www.khl.com{item-links/item-link[@id=2]/items/item[1]/derived-files/preview}" />
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;</xsl:text>
  </description>
  <pubDate><xsl:apply-templates select="creation-date" mode="date-format"/><xsl:value-of select="substring(creation-date,11,16)"/><xsl:text>:</xsl:text>00 GMT</pubDate>
  <guid>http://www.khl.com<xsl:value-of select="$magazine_path" />/detail/<xsl:value-of select="link" /></guid>
</item>
```

Of course, you still have to ensure the **src** attributes are being written out as the correct value, and actually refer to images that actually exist!